# Arch Linux system update: error: GPGME error: No data

Tags: linux, archlinux, pacman-package-manager

When I finally decided to upgrade my laptop running vanilla Arch Linux (because of internet problems) I kept on getting errors like this:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
 core                     126.8 KiB   125K/s 00:01 [######################] 100%
 extra                   1639.9 KiB   221K/s 00:07 [######################] 100%
 community                  4.2 MiB   169K/s 00:26 [######################] 100%
 multilib                 168.6 KiB   169K/s 00:01 [######################] 100%
 archlinuxfr               11.5 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 xorg116                    6.3 KiB  20.5K/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 xorg116.sig                6.3 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update xorg116 (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
 catalyst                   6.3 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
 catalyst.sig               6.4 KiB  0.00B/s 00:00 [######################] 100%
error: GPGME error: No data
error: failed to update catalyst (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature)) 
error: database 'xorg116' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
error: database 'catalyst' is not valid (invalid or corrupted database (PGP signature))
```

I haven't updated/upgraded for nearly a month or more because of internet issues. I tried all the things people suggested to do on other websites including stack overflow but none of them worked.

What I tried:

```
$ sudo pacman -Rdd catalyst                             47.6s  Fri 21:44
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
error: target not found: catalyst

$ sudo pacman -Syu                                              Fri 21:44
error: GPGME error: No data
error: GPGME error: No data
**and the same thing as "$ sudo pacman -Syu"**

This is also the same output for $ sudo pacman -Syy
```

I have also tried

```
$ sudo pacman -Scc
$ sudo pacman-key --init
$ sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux                     1394ms  Fri 
==> Appending keys from archlinux.gpg...
==> Locally signing trusted keys in keyring...
  -> Locally signing key DDB867B92AA789C165EEFA799B729B06A680C281...
  -> Locally signing key 684148BB25B49E986A4944C55184252D824B18E8...
  -> Locally signing key 91FFE0700E80619CEB73235CA88E23E377514E00...
  -> Locally signing key AB19265E5D7D20687D303246BA1DFB64FFF979E7...
  -> Locally signing key 0E8B644079F599DFC1DDC3973348882F6AC6A4C2...
 ==> Importing owner trust values...
==> Disabling revoked keys in keyring...
  -> Disabling key 7FA647CD89891DEDC060287BB9113D1ED21E1A55...
  -> Disabling key D4DE5ABDE2A7287644EAC7E36D1A9E70E19DAA50...
  -> Disabling key 40440DC037C05620984379A6761FAD69BA06C6A9...
  -> Disabling key B1F2C889CB2CCB2ADA36D963097D629E437520BD...
  -> Disabling key BC1FBE4D2826A0B51E47ED62E2539214C6C11350...
  -> Disabling key 63F395DE2D6398BBE458F281F2DBB4931985A992...
  -> Disabling key 8F76BEEA0289F9E1D3E229C05F946DED983D4366...
  -> Disabling key 4FCF887689C41B09506BE8D5F3E1D5C5D30DB0AD...
  -> Disabling key 81D7F8241DB38BC759C80FCE3A726C6170E80477...
  -> Disabling key 5E7585ADFF106BFFBBA319DC654B877A0864983E...
  -> Disabling key E7210A59715F6940CF9A4E36A001876699AD6E84...
  -> Disabling key F5A361A3A13554B85E57DDDAAF7EF7873CFD4BB6...
  -> Disabling key 8CF934E339CAD8ABF342E822E711306E3C4F88BC...
  -> Disabling key 5696C003B0854206450C8E5BE613C09CB4440678...
  -> Disabling key 9515D8A8EAB88E49BB65EDBCE6B456CAF15447D5...
  -> Disabling key 4A8B17E20B88ACA61860009B5CED81B7C2E5C0D2...
  -> Disabling key 0B20CA1931F5DA3A70D0F8D2EA6836E1AB441196...
  -> Disabling key 34C5D94FE7E7913E86DC427E7FB1A3800C84C0A5...
  -> Disabling key 39F880E50E49A4D11341E8F939E4F17F295AFBF4...
  -> Disabling key 66BD74A036D522F51DD70A3C7F2A16726521E06D...
  -> Disabling key 44D4A033AC140143927397D47EFD567D4C7EA887...
  -> Disabling key 27FFC4769E19F096D41D9265A04F9397CDFD6BB0...
==> Updating trust database...
gpg: next trustdb check due at 2018-06-25
```

But nothing worked, no changes at all.
Anyone know why this is happening? Is it perhaps because I didn't update Arch Linux for such a long time? How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question about the game or the package manager? Read the tag [tag:pacman] description.

Comment: Have you uncommented your mirror(s)? http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors checkout this documentation: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101651

Answer (score 50):

**Remove and then update**

in terminal

1. $ `sudo rm -R /var/lib/pacman/sync`
2. $ `sudo pacman -Syu`

Comment: This seems to work for me for `pacman`, but not for `sudo pamac update -a`. Any idea what to do?

Comment: I know it is probably too late for this, but it may helps another fellow travelers may be passing by: for pamac the trick was to force a refresh, just like this: `pamac upgrade --force-refresh`

I had the same issue bugging me for at least 4 days now! And its gone!

Comment: I am using pacman version 6.0.2 and the force-refresh command isn't recognized. Though the first commands still seem to work just fine.

Comment: @McloHrk The update to the answer is wrong. @Dennis Braga was talking about `pamac` the pacman wrapper. Pacman itself has no such command & option. So it's not even a true alternative unless one uses `pamac`.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me.

```bash
sudo rm -rf /etc/pacman.d/gnupg /var/lib/pacman/sync
sudo pacman-key --init 
sudo pacman -Syyu
```

The last command hit errors at

```
checking keys in keyring

error: key "6D42BDD116E0068F" could not be looked up remotely
error: required key missing from keyring
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
```

We've to update the `archlinux-keyring` package to remedy this

```bash
sudo pacman -S archlinux-keyring
```

However, this presented the [chicken-egg problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg).  We need the package to validate other packages, but its own package is now outdated too.  The above command downloads `archlinux-keyring-yyymmdd.pkg.tar.zst`; unable to validate, rejects it.  There's a prompt question about the failure, after which irrespective of the answer the downloaded package gets deleted.

Without answering to the prompt, I opened another terminal window and copied the downloaded package.  Dismissed the prompt in the previous terminal and manually installed the copied package.

```bash
cp /var/cache/pacman/pkg/archlinux-keyring-20220713-1-any.pkg.tar.zst ~/tmp/
sudo pacman -U ~/tmp/archlinux-keyring-20220713-1-any.pkg.tar.zst
```

Now things work fine when I go `sudo pacman -Syu` as usual.

Answer (score 2):

**I did:** 
First make sure the first mirror in `[sudo vim /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist]` is whitelisted, Then:

```
sudo rm -R /var/lib/pacman/sync
```

If you use **e2guardian** (or similar tools), make sure '**blanket block for SSL**' is not enabled in `[examplef1.story]`. and at the End:

```
sudo pacman-key --init

sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux

sudo -E pacman -Syu

sudo pacman -Syyu
```

**Source:** [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1983577#p1983577):

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are not running a "vanilla Arch Linux", when you have custom repositories (archlinuxfr, xorg116, catalyst) enabled. You can disable them in `/etc/pacman.conf`

Regarding to your problem you most likely don't have the neccessary keys for the repositories installed. You can enable signed unofficial user repositories via `pacman-key -r Key-ID`. If this does not work, you may also disable checking the signature.

See also [AMD Catalyst](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small script from all the suggestions here and some other forums. Hope this helps another struggling soul for a fix.

```
    #!/bin/sh
echo "::file: /usr/local/bin/fix-gpme-arch.sh"
    echo "Thanks to folks at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48117783/arch-linux-system-update-error-gpgme-error-no-data and other forums"
    echo "#######"
    echo ""
    echo ""
    echo ":: Script to fix GPME error"
    echo ""
    sleep 1
    
    echo "Remove files: /etc/pacman.d/gnupg and /var/lib/pacman/sync"
    echo ""
    sudo rm -rfv /etc/pacman.d/gnupg /var/lib/pacman/sync
    sleep 1
    
    echo ""
    echo "Reinitialize pacman keys"
    echo ""
    echo ":: pacman-key --init"
    echo ""
    sudo pacman-key --init 
    echo ""
    echo ":: pacman-key --populate archlinux"
    echo ""
    sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux
    echo ""
    sleep 1
    
    echo "Update pacman database"
    echo ""
    echo ":: pacman -Fyy"
    echo ""
    sudo pacman -Fyy
    echo ""
    echo "::sudo -E pacman -Syu"
    sudo -E pacman -Syu
    echo ""
    echo ":: pacman -Syyu"
    echo ""
    sudo pacman -Syyu
    echo ""
    sleep 1
    
    echo "GPME fix error done"
    echo ""
    echo "If you see further errors, suggest running: pacman -S archlinux-keyring"
    echo ""
    
    exit 0
```